# Is it possible to transfer value between two cryptocurrencies?

Tags: exchanges, btcrelay

I am interested in whether it is possible to use Ethereum to execute an exchange between two different crypto-currencies, such that the funds are released only once both parties have agreed and in some manner 'committed' to the transaction.

For example Alice is selling 1 BTC and wants to buy LTC, and Bob wants BTC and is willing to sell LTC - both sides have agreed a price.

As far as I understand the https://github.com/ethereum/btcrelay project would allow validation of a multi-sig transaction from Bitcoin, but can this be extended easily?

Edit: I imagine acting as a central entity to match counterparties, this is specifically about the execution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Btc relay makes it possible. It can be extended to other cryptocurrencies.
Also check out etherex, a decentralized cryptoexchange.

Comment: Thank you, and good to know! Is there any material you would recommend for me on how to get started. I am relatively new to the crypto world but have good general tech skills and would like to build a prototype.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell btcrelay makes transaction history available within Ethereum but there is no way to actually *execute* a transaction on Bitcoin - is my understanding correct?